# Blocked IP addresses yet still showing up in HTTP access logs

Tags: networking, centos

I'm having some issues blocking IP addresses in my CentOS server.  I'm using Advance Policy Firewall and I've added the IP addresses to the deny_hosts.rules file. I've stopped and restarted the service yet the addresses that I added to that file keep showing up in the HTTP access logs.

These IP addresses I'm trying to block are accessing my site a few hundred times every hour and it's spawning lots of HTTPD processes causing high load.

**UPDATE**

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon Sep 19 06:42:07 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [100260:7590308]
:INPUT ACCEPT [100260:7590308]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [92161:131448392]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [92161:131448392]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 19 06:42:07 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon Sep 19 06:42:07 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [100252:7589968]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [92159:131448300]
COMMIT
```

Comment: Perhaps you could give more informations? like: firewall-cmd --list-all-zones . And also this: iptables-save -c

Comment: @A.B I have updated the original post with the output of iptables-save. The other command firewall-cmd --list-all-zones doesn't work.

Comment: i believe I have it resolved. I forgot to remove apf off of development mode so the rules where getting flushed every 5 minutes. Oops!

Comment: @EliseCrane Consider [answering your question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). By accepting your own answer you will formally mark the question as solved and this will help future users with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgot to turn developer mode of on APF which was causing the iptable rules to be cleared every five minutes.